# mapo binding broken during nomal / rank games

Tags: dota-2

been playing meepo for quite sometime now and its annoying that after the update . when i play normal or rank games my bindings wont work.

but during practice / lobby game it works fine.

can anyone help me ? thanks!

this is the binding i made.

```
alias "tab1" "dota_cycle_selected;"

alias "poff1" "dota_ability_execute 1;"

alias "poff2" "dota_ability_execute 1; dota_ability_execute 1;"

alias "tab2" "tab1; poff2;"

alias "imbapoff" "tab2; tab2; tab2; tab2; tab2;"

bind "x" "imbapoff"

alias "selectpoff1" "dota_ability_execute 1; +sixense_Left_click; -sixense_Left_click; tab1;"

alias "selectpoff2" "selectpoff1"

bind "z" "selectpoff2"
```

and here's my way of activating it. copied this to the auto exec.cfg

```
bind "KP_8" "exec meepo.cfg"
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be intentional.

As of [May 24, 2016](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/May_24,_2016_Patch):

> A key input can no longer be bound to multiple console commands, except when cheats are on or spectating.

You're not *directly* binding keys to multiple commands, but judging from them still working in practice and lobby games, I suspect you've fallen foul of this change.